# Trouble inserting two values with array_push() in a while loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to count the occurrences of certain dates in my MySQL table using a PHP `while` loop and place the date and number of repetitions in an `array`. I am able to properly add the date to the array, but I cannot seem to add the number of repetitions to it.

Example:

```
function counter() {
//The 'timestamp' column uses the MySQL timestamp type
$query = mysql_query("SELECT timestamp FROM table1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC");

$date_c;
$counter = 0;
$date_array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    //gets the year, month, and day from the timestamp
    $year = substr($row['timestamp'], 0, 4);
    $month = substr($row['timestamp'], 5, 2);
    $day = substr($row['timestamp'], 8, 2);
    $date = $month.'/'.$day.'/'.$year;

    if($date == $date_c) {
        $counter += 1;
    } else {
        array_push($date_array, $date, $counter);
        $counter = 0;
    }

    $date_c = $date;
```

However, when I `echo` part of the array the counter does not update. Here is an example using the first repeated date in `table1`:

```
>>> echo $date;
06/15/2012
>>> echo $counter;
25
>>> echo $date_array[0];
06/15/2012
>>> echo $date_array[1];
0
```

I have played around with this for a while but I can't seem to find my error. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there anything else you want to do with those rows? Because this seems easier to me:

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(timestamp,'%m/%d/%Y') as 'date', COUNT(*) as 'count'
 FROM table1 
 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(timestamp,'%m/%d/%Y')
 ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

... and the problem in the php code might be the last date / count isn't pushed to `$date_array` (the array_push will have to run once more *after* the while loop is finished, if the last iteration did NOT push a counter on the array.....)

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with Wrikken that you can get the count of unique dates in SQL, rather than needing to do it in PHP.

However, if you do want to count the instances of each date, I would use the associative array feature of arrays in PHP.  So something like:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT timestamp FROM table1");
$date_array = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $year = substr($row['timestamp'], 0, 4);
    $month = substr($row['timestamp'], 5, 2);
    $day = substr($row['timestamp'], 8, 2);

    $date = $month.'/'.$day.'/'.$year;

    // Using the @ symbol to suppress warnings for missing index
    @ $date_array[$date]++;
}

print_r($date_array);
```

At the end of that loop, $date_array is an associative array with the date as the key, and the number of occurrences as the value.